# Ruby / Gmail gem to grab Sent Messages

Tags: ruby, gmail

How do I get sent messages from the gmail gem? I don't see the option in the docs: http://rubydoc.info/gems/gmail

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sent Messages should be a label.

```
gmail.label("Sent Mail").emails
```

I'm now sure about the name. You can get the list of all labels using

```
gmail.labels.all
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this should work for you

```
gmail.label("sent").emails {|email| ... }
```